# Hot reload is not working with Blazor app

Tags: asp.net, blazor, hot-reload, hot-module-replacement

So I watched this demo from Steve Sanderson (https://youtu.be/MiLAE6HMr10?t=2018) where he makes changed to his files and the change is instantly reflected in the front-end. I cannot get this to work on my machine.

I have tried creating a Blazor app with several different hosting models, Web Assembly hosting, Web Assembly with ASP.NET backend and only server side hosting, but none of these models have the instant update feature. If I run from inside VS with IIS I need to manually reload the app. If I use `dotnet watch run` the app still needs to shut down and rebuild every time I make a change, which takes 20-30 seconds, and I still have to refresh my web page. This is way too long when you're making changes often and want to see what they look like in real time. What is the trick for making it work like in the demo?

Comment: I have the same problem